# How to locate and count the number of words in a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So want to  count the occurrences of contaminants but some cases has more than one contaminants so when I use the value_counts it counts them as one. For example "Gasoline, Diesel = 8" How would I count the them as separate without doing it manually.

And would it be possible to create a function that would make it easier to categorize them into lets say 4 types of contaminant? I just need a clue or a simple explanation on what I need to do.

`data=pd.read_csv('Data gathered.csv') data`

```
data['CONTAMINANTS'].value_counts().plot(kind = 'barh').invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(15).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contaminants are always separated by commas in your data, you can use [`pandas.Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to get them into lists. Then you can get them into distinct rows with [`pandas.DataFrame.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), which finally allows using the `value_counts()` method.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'File Number': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                     'CONTAMINANTS': ['ACENAPHTENE, ANTHRACENE, BENZ-A-ANTHRACENE', 
                                      'CHLORINATED SOLVENTS', 
                                      'DIESEL, GASOLINE, ACENAPHTENE', 
                                      'GASOLINE, ACENAPHTENE']})
data
```

```
    File Number     CONTAMINANTS
0   1               ACENAPHTENE, ANTHRACENE, BENZ-A-ANTHRACENE
1   2               CHLORINATED SOLVENTS
2   3               DIESEL, GASOLINE, ACENAPHTENE
3   4               GASOLINE, ACENAPHTENE
```

```py
data['CONTAMINANTS'] = data['CONTAMINANTS'].str.split(pat=', ')
data_long = data.explode('CONTAMINANTS')
data_long['CONTAMINANTS'].value_counts()
```

```
ACENAPHTENE             3
GASOLINE                2
DIESEL                  1
ANTHRACENE              1
BENZ-A-ANTHRACENE       1
CHLORINATED SOLVENTS    1
Name: CONTAMINANTS, dtype: int64
```

To categorize the contaminants, you could define a dictionary that maps them to types. Then you can use that dictionary to add a column of types to the exploded dataframe:

```py
types = {'ACENAPHTENE': 1, 
         'GASOLINE': 2,
         'DIESEL': 2, 
         'ANTHRACENE': 1,
         'BENZ-A-ANTHRACENE': 1,
         'CHLORINATED SOLVENTS': 3}

data_long['contaminant type'] = data_long['CONTAMINANTS'].apply(lambda x: types[x])
data_long
```

```
    File Number     CONTAMINANTS            contaminant type
0   1               ACENAPHTENE             1
0   1               ANTHRACENE              1
0   1               BENZ-A-ANTHRACENE       1
1   2               CHLORINATED SOLVENTS    3
2   3               DIESEL                  2
2   3               GASOLINE                2
2   3               ACENAPHTENE             1
3   4               GASOLINE                2
3   4               ACENAPHTENE             1
```

Comment: Hello why am I getting an error '6'

`ACT = {'0': 'No Activity', 
         '1A' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED',
         '1B' : 'CONTAMINATION CONFIRMED', 
         '2A' :'INVESTIGATION',
         '2B': 'INVESTIGATION',
         '3':'CORRECTIVE ACTION PLANNING',
         '4': 'IMPLEMENT ACTION',
        '5': 'MONITOR ACTION',
         '6A':'ACTION COMPLETED',
         '6B':'ACTION COMPLETED',
        '6C': 'INACTIVE',
         '6D': 'INACTIVE'
          }`

     `data['STATUS'] = data['ACT-STATUS'].apply(lambda x: ACT[x])
        data`

Comment: Hi @geo_codernoob - maybe one of the values in `data['ACT-STATUS']` is `'6'`? Then the `apply()` method would try to look up `ACT['6']`, which you haven't defined.

Comment: Hi, Can you explain what does the lambda do?

Comment: It's a shortcut way to define a function, useful if you only need the function in one place and it does not need a name. In this case, `df.apply()` expects a function as its argument, but `types` is a dictionary, so we transform the dictionary into a function by using the `lambda` keyword. See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda